# Is it possible to calculate the desired area analytically?

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, functions, mathematical-optimization, symbolic

I have the three two-variable curves $f,g,h$ with $0\leq x\leq \frac {\pi}{2} $ and $0 \leq y \leq \pi$

I use  ContourPlot as

```
f := Cos[x] + 2 Cos[x - 2 y];
 g := Cos[x - y] + 2 Cos[x + y];
 h := Cos[2 x - y] + 2 Cos[y];

ContourPlot[{f == 0, g == 0, h == 0}, {x, 0, \[Pi]/2}, {y, 0, \[Pi]}]
```

and I get the attached plot. I want to calculate the area between these curves (the upper part, the lower part, and the area between the middle curves).

**My question:**

> Is it possible to do that analytically?

[image]

Comment: If you define `g[x_, y_] := Cos[x - y] + 2 Cos[x + y]` then `f=g[x - y, -y]`and `h=g[x, y - x]`. Maybe it is helpful...

Comment: Yes it is possible. This is a simple integration problem.

Comment: I think it is impossible in Mathematica. `3.15373`

Comment: Another comment. If we set `ArcTan[x]`, `ArcTan[y]` for `x` and  `y`, respectively, we get the following simple equations for the region borders `4 y x == -3 + y^2`, `3 - x y == 0` and `3 + x^2 + 2 x y == 0`.

Answer (score 2):

***Partial answer here.***

This is quite a brute force method. Nevertheless it gives a partial analytic result. Will give the generating expression and results, instead of showing all the work to avoid clutter.

### Setup

1. Find the analytic expressions for the curves. Solving for `f, g, h`

   - `Solve[f == 0]` gave 8 results. Manually picked/simplified for your two blue curves.

     - `y0 = -ArcCos[-(1/2) Sqrt[2 - Cos[x]^2 - Sqrt[4 - 5 Cos[x]^2 + Cos[x]^4]]]`
     - `y3 = ArcCos[-(1/2) Sqrt[2 - Cos[x]^2 - Sqrt[4 - 5 Cos[x]^2 + Cos[x]^4]]]`
   - `Solve[g == 0]` gave 4 results. Manually picked/simplified for your yellow curve.

     - `y1 = -ArcCos[-(Sqrt[Sin[x]^2]/Sqrt[1 + 8 Cos[x]^2])]`
   - `Solve[h == 0, y]` gave 4 results. Manually picked/simplified for your green curve.

     - `y2 = ArcCos[-(Sin[2 x]/Sqrt[5 + 4 Cos[2 x]])]`
2. Find the one intersection for `f` and `g`

   - `Solve[{f == 0, g == 0}]` gave 12 results.
   - But, only only result satisfying the intersection near `(0.66,1.32)` is `(xfg, yfg)`

     - `xfg = ArcTan[Sqrt[3/5]]`
     - `yfg = ArcTan[Sqrt[15]])`
3. Now it is straightforward to perform the analytical integration using Mathematica.

### Solving for Area

```
Abox = \[Pi]/2*\[Pi];
AUnderY3 = Integrate[FullSimplify@y3, {x, 0, xmax}];
AUnderY2 = Integrate[FullSimplify@y2, {x, 0, xmax}];
ABweenY1Y0 = Integrate[FullSimplify@(y1 - y0), {x, 0, xfg}];
ABweenY0Y1 = Integrate[FullSimplify@(y0 - y1), {x, xfg, xmax}];
```

Only one of the above expressions gave a closed form analytical expression.

```
AUnderY2 = 1/12 (4 \[Pi]^2 - 3 (2 Log[2]^2 + PolyLog[2, 1/4]))
```

All the other expressions failed to resolve to anything in a closed form. However, if you evaluate the following expression numerically, you get the correct result that @cvgmt posted.

```
N@(Abox - AUnderY3 + AUnderY2 - ABweenY1Y0 - ABweenY0Y1) = 3.15374
```

Maybe there are ways to simplify/integrate other area expressions to get closed forms as well. The problematic functions are `y0` and `y3`. `y1` and `y2` both have closed forms for straight-up integration.

Answer (score 0):

You can get analytical expressions for all integrals if you solve curves f and g for x[y] and h for y[x].

Have a look at the plot.

```
f = Cos[x] + 2 Cos[x - 2 y];
g = Cos[x - y] + 2 Cos[x + y];
h = Cos[2 x - y] + 2 Cos[y];

ContourPlot[{f == 0, g == 0, h == 0}, {x, 0, \[Pi]/2}, {y, 0, \[Pi]}, 
ContourStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}, 
GridLines -> (gl = 
Evaluate@{Table[i, {i, 0, Pi/2, Pi/6}], 
  Table[i, {i, 0, Pi, Pi/6}]}), FrameTicks -> gl]
```

For simplification i eliminated Sin or Cos in equations.

```
eli11 = Eliminate[{TrigExpand[f] == 0, Sin[x]^2 + Cos[x]^2 == 1, 
Sin[y]^2 + Cos[y]^2 == 1}, {Sin[x], Sin[y]}]

sol11a = First@
Solve[eli11 && 0 < x < Pi/2 && 2/3 Pi < y < Pi, x, Reals] // 
ToRadicals

int11a = Integrate[x /. sol11a, {y, 2/3 Pi, Pi}]

(*   1/36 (4 \[Pi]^2 - 9 Log[2]^2 - 9 PolyLog[2, -(1/2) (-1)^(2/3)] - 
 9 PolyLog[2, 1/4 + (I Sqrt[3])/4])   *)

sol11b = First@
Solve[eli11 && 0 < x < Pi/2 && Pi/3 < y < Pi/2, x, Reals] // 
ToRadicals

int11b = Integrate[x /. sol11b, {y, Pi/3, Pi/2}]

(*   1/72 (5 \[Pi]^2 + 36 PolyLog[2, -(1/2)] - 
 18 PolyLog[2, 1/2 (-1)^(1/3)] - 18 PolyLog[2, 1/4 (1 -  I Sqrt[3])])   *)

eli12 = Eliminate[{TrigExpand[g] == 0, Sin[x]^2 + Cos[x]^2 == 1, 
Sin[y]^2 + Cos[y]^2 == 1}, {Sin[x], Sin[y]}]

sol12 = First@Solve[eli12 && 0 < x < Pi/2 && 0 < y < Pi/2, x, Reals]

int12 = Integrate[x /. sol12, {y, 0, Pi/2}]

(*   1/12 (2 \[Pi]^2 - 3 Log[2]^2 - 6 PolyLog[2, -(1/2)])   *)

eli13 = Eliminate[{TrigExpand[h] == 0, Sin[x]^2 + Cos[x]^2 == 1, 
Sin[y]^2 + Cos[y]^2 == 1}, {Sin[x], Cos[y]}]

sol13 = First@
Solve[eli13 && 0 < x < Pi/2 && Pi/2 < y < 2/3 Pi, y, Reals] // 
ToRadicals

int13 = Integrate[y /. sol13, {x, 0, Pi/2}]

(*   1/24 (7 \[Pi]^2 - 6 Log[2]^2 - 12 PolyLog[2, -(1/2)])   *)
```

I leave it to you to integrate til the intersection point and to subtract.